# Trying to load data into a new view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an issue attempting to create a "clone" of data on a page. The summary is that I have a create customer jobs screen and a separate manage customer jobs screen. These both work fine. I have a need to "clone" already existing customer job data to create a new similar set of jobs. So in my management screen, I have a clone button. I want this to head off to my "create" page with the data pre-populated with the original data, minus one or two pertinent identifying pieces of information, e.g. Job Name.

My issue is I cannot seem to get the post to redirect off to the Create page with my new data in the view model. I can't have a submit action as this saves the data; the data I'm cloning won't be persisted between the manage and create screens.

Here is where I'm at:

In my CSHTML:

```
  <button type="button" name="btnClone" value="btnClone" id="btnClone" formaction="CloneJob" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 150px;">Clone</button>
```

This fires off a click event to grab the current jobId which then fires off this function:

```
function CloneJob(jobId) {
$.post('CloneJob', { JobId: jobId }, function (data) {
    window.document(data);
});
```

}

In my controller, I have this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CloneJob(Guid jobId) {
   // logic which wipes off the old data job from the view model
   // eg names, ids, etc. but leaves the actual job details intact

return View("CreateJob", manageJobViewModel);
```

From this, I can see the HTML being returned in the IE/Chrome debug network section, but it won't go off to my CreateJob view populated with the data.

What am I missing?

Comment: In your controller, the comment seems to suggest that you expect to have a fully populated JobViewModel, which would not be the case. Controllers don't persist state information between requests unless you program them to do so. I think that all you need to do is to create the JobModelView from the database using the jobId that you passed in.

Comment: The logic I have left out does actually populate the JobViewModel. I just grab the session view model, clean it up and that's what ends up as the manageJobViewModel that I want to return to my CreateJobs screen. I'm happy that this logic works as I can see it's as it should be when I debug.

Comment: If you can see the populated JobViewModel in the debugger before 'return View' then it *should* work.I've never seen the 'window.document(...)' syntax before. I'd generally 'window.document.body.innerHtml =' but I would only load the part of the page that presents inside the body tag. You could use the Fiddler web debugger to see what precisely is being sent to the browser.

Comment: I have managed to get further in that it now "works". My controller is unchanged, but my javascript is now:  $.when($.get('CloneJob', {jobId: jobId})).then(function (response) { $("body").html(response); }); I'm aware that this is still ajax, but in the face of an alternative that is more technically acceptable, this does work. Would be happy to take any advaces for a more technically neater approach as I understand that this is a bit of a misuse of ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this cracked.

My cshtml now contains this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Clone Job", "CloneJob", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @style = "width: 150px" })
```

My controller just grabs the current viewmodel from the session and uses it to clone the job. Then, the controller now simply returns the view with the new model I set up within the method.

```
return View("CreateJob",  clonedJobViewModel);
```

It's simple now when I look at it, but it's the getting there part.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're going to replace the entire tab/window contents, don't use AJAX. There's no point, and it's just something extra to maintain. Utilize a standard link, instead. Second, a POST should only be made when something is changing. This here should just be a simple GET request.

Create a link to the "create" URL and pass an id for the job that's being cloned. In the create action, then, you can look up that job from the database, based on that id, populate your view model with the data, and return it with the view.

If you want the appearance of a button, you can just style the link to look like a button, but you should use a standard old `<a>` tag, because that's the semantic meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get further in that it now "works". My controller is unchanged, but my javascript is now:

```
$.when($.get('CloneJob', {jobId: jobId}))
.then(function (response) 
{ $("body").html(response); });
```

I'm aware that this is still ajax, but in the face of an alternative that is more technically acceptable, this does work. Would be happy to take any advaces for a more technically neater approach as I understand that this is a bit of a misuse of ajax.